# ERROR: subquery must return only one column width many SELECT

Tags: postgresql, select

Multi SELECT in PostgreSQL return this poroblem :(

```
SELECT date::date,
(
    SELECT concat_ws(' ', user_cards.last_name, user_cards.first_name, user_cards.father_name),
        (SELECT MIN(start_time) FROM calls_moizvonki WHERE user_account = user_cards.email AND answer_time::date=date AND answered=1) AS start_day,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calls_moizvonki WHERE user_account = user_cards.email AND answer_time::date=date AND answered=1) AS calls,
        (SELECT AVG(duration) FROM calls_moizvonki WHERE user_account = user_cards.email AND answer_time::date=date AND answered=1 AND duration>10) AS duration
    FROM user_cards
)
FROM generate_series(
  '2022-01-20%'::date,
  '2022-01-24'::date,
  '1 day'::interval
) date;
```

ERROR: subquery must return only one column width many

Comment: this is because, the subquery within the select statement is returning more than one column

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Hint: use a correlated query!!!